# Garbled screen graphics after wake up Macbook from full battery drain

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, graphics, restart

A couple times now when my Macbook Pro running Yosemite was left unplugged overnight (with the screen open) I have come back to it like this [image: image of garbled screen]
(That's the drained battery symbol that indicates you need to plug in your Mac) 
The graphics continue to be garbled like that when it starts up after some charging. The problem is resolved when the computer restarts.

My question is: should I be concerned by this? I have never seen this on other Apple devices. My device is still under warranty, so I could take it in, but if it's not really a problem / won't get worse than this, maybe not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a 2008 15" MacBook Pro that does the same thing. Every time the battery drains, and I plug it back in, the screen will be completely distorted (but will go back to normal after reboot). Apple has replaced my logic board twice for this problem, and it still occurs. It's just an annoyance, as the laptop is still running great 7 years later. I wouldn't worry too much about it, unless it begins to happen while using the OS.

Comment: If replacing the logic board the first time didn't work, why did they do it again?

Comment: @shim Because the issue persisted after the first replacement, and I was concerned, and the only thing Apple's Genius Bar could think of to do was try to replace the board again.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a macbookpro mid 2015 and after 3 day the video card crashed, so I tooked it to the store and they gave me a new one.

After a month usin the new computer I got this screen when the battery drained, so I went back to the store and they replaced my computer again.

Now, 3 days after using the new computer I just realized it does the same thing, so I have to go back to the store :/

They have a great service though -

Comment: Apple devices are not reliable anymore like Jobs era. Now, you will see long queues at Apple Stores or Service Centers.